# How to get Spring Security auto logout time, when using invalidate-session="false"?

Tags: spring, spring-security, listener, logout, expired-sessions

I use spring security 3.2 ver.

And my logout option have invalidate-session="false".

So i can't use session listener.

How to get auto logout time?

Do not click logout button.

And spring security have token listener or credential listener?

Comment: Do you see that wide buttons on the left and right bottom corners of your keyboard?

Comment: sorry i edit uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

you have add tag into spring security file

```
<security:session-management>
            <security:concurrency-control
                max-sessions="1" />
</security:session-management>
```

auto-log out after you have not used.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong, so I can delete my answer, cant you add something like below in your web.xml :

```
 <session-config>
        <session-timeout>1440</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
```

I am having hard time understanding your question because your grammar is very awkward. I presume you want to set some time after which the session expires, is logged out. 
YOu can also use something like this below for session-management :

```
 <security:session-management session-fixation-protection="invalidateSession">
         <security:concurrency-control session-registry-ref="sessionRegistry" max-sessions="1" expired-url="/login"/>
     </security:session-management>
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.